# Convergence of Power Series with $z^{2^k}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

So i got this  power series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^k \cdot z^{2^k}$$

Can i do the convergence test like this:

$$\text{ratio test} \Longrightarrow \frac{3^{k+1}\cdot z^{2^{k+1}}}{3^k \cdot z^{2^k}} = \frac{3 \cdot z^{2^{k+1}}}{z^{2^k}} = 3 \cdot z^2 \lt 1 \Longleftrightarrow |z| < \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{z^{2^{k+1}}}{z^{2^k}} = z^{2^{k+1}-2^k} = z^{2^k(2-1)} = z^{2^k} \ne z^2 \text{ (unless $k=1$)}. \qquad$

Comment: Indeed i misinterpret $z^{2^{k+1}}$ as $(z^2)^{k+1}$

Comment: So considering this i would get $|z| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt[2^k]{3}}$ . Can i write it just like that?

Comment: Of course $\lt $ and not $\le$ . [I cant edit my comments for a reason]

Comment: You've omitted the fact that you need to take a limit as $k\to\infty.$

Comment: Yes that would be my next step. Ty for your help.

Comment: Notice that $k=0$ in the first term of the series, and $k=1$ in the next term, and $k=2$ in the next, and so on. But what is $k$ equal to if one proposes that $1/\sqrt[2^k] 3$ is the radius of convergence? $\qquad$

Comment: $$
\frac{3^{k+1}\cdot z^{2^{k+1}}}{3^k \cdot z^{2^k}} = 3 z^{2^k} \to \begin{cases} 0 \text{ as } k\to\infty & \text{if } |z|<1, \\ \infty \text{ as } k\to\infty & \text{if } |z|>1. \end{cases}
$$
But this is _not_ a valid application of the ratio test, since since the ratio is not of the $(n+1)$th-degree term to the $n$th-degree term.  See Don Antonio's answer. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see your series as a power series, observe that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^k z^{2^k}=1\cdot z+3z^2+9z^4+\cdots+3^kz^{2^k}+\cdots$$

observe then that the sequence of coefficients is

$$a_n:=\begin{cases}0,&n\neq 2^k\\{}\\3^k,&n=2^k\end{cases}$$

Thus, the convergence radius is given by (the sequence above is non-negative):

$$\frac1R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n=2^k\to\infty\iff k\to\infty}3^{k/2^k}=1\implies R=1$$

Answer (score -1):

The Ratio test gives the limit $ L=\lim_{k\to +\infty} 3|z|^{2^k}$.

- $|z|<1\implies L=0\implies R\geq 1$
- $|z|=1 $ and $ \sum 3^k $ diverges $\implies R\leq 1$

thus, the radius of convergence is $R=1$.