# Radius of convergence for an unusual series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm working through a pair of power series questions.  Find the radius of convergence for the following series:

(1) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n/2}x^n$

(2) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n/2}x^{2^n}$

The unusual series is the second one.  It has the term $x^{2^n}$.  In particular its exponent is $2^n$ and I'm not sure how to proceed for figuring out its radius of convergence.

How would you figure out the radius of convergence?  What would you use to do this?

Comment: Very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3267501, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2061302

Comment: You can use the ratio test for numerical series.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Thank you for the similar problems. I wasn't sure if the exponent changed the results significantly.